# When set to sleep, laptop restarts instead

Tags: windows-10, power, windows-10-v2004

When I click 'Sleep', my laptop restarts for no reason. It is brand new. It shouldn't be doing this. I have ran power troubleshooter, which said that there is no problem, and I have ran SFC and DISM scan, returning nothing. Please help.

Comment: Run [powercfg /energy](https://fossbytes.com/powercfg-check-battery-capacity-battery-health-report-windows-using-cmd/) and post the report.

Comment: Look in your power manager settings (Windows Power Management).  The Sleep button / function may have been set to turn the machine off. Then shut off may for some reason restart the computer. Go through these settings very carefully.

Comment: Have you tried testing Sleep from the CMD prompt? See https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-sleep-windows-10-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this is a bug in Windows 10 2004 for my laptop. I reverted back to the previous Windows installation, and the issue was resolved.